# SonarQube overall coverage for JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sonarqube, code-coverage

I'm currently providing JavaScript lcov reports for both unit and integration tests and they're properly displayed. However SonarQube doesn't seem to calculate the overall coverage for some reason - I have a Java project where this functionality works for my Java code.

Is this functionality supported? If not is there a feature request for it or can I file a feature request somewhere?

**Update**
Or at least is there a way to manually pass the overall coverage. I can manually combine my lcov reports.

Comment: what tools do you use to generate test report and code coverage for your javascript code?

Comment: istanbul for integration (protractor) tests and isparta for unit (karma) tests

Comment: And the problem is that the percent of code coverage is not displayed on sonarqube, that's right?

Comment: No. The percentage is displayed for both unit and integration tests. What I would like is to get the overall coverage like you can see here - https://aroundthecode.files.wordpress.com/2014/07/schermata-2014-07-07-alle-23-31-55.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's currently no way to have overall coverage for JavaScript (besides coding a custom plugin).
According to the [current plan](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-6202), SonarQube 5.4 will compute overall coverage for all languages based on unit and integration test coverage.